# Set the height of a table in percentage from remaining page height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a web page which I have designed already. In this the header part is taking up 161px in height. The remaining space I've got is `calc(100vh - 161px)`. In this space I have two tables. I want to also have a scrollbar for this table. For that I need to set the height for this `tbody` and `overflow-y: auto`.

I want the height to be 30% for the first table and 70% to the second table so that it will work on all the devices which are more than 768px.

How can I set the height of this tables ?

Comment: It would really be a lot easier for us to answer if you include a working example of what you have.

Comment: Sure I will add that

Comment: Actually, its a very big lines of code so that is why I am not able to add that

Comment: Okay I will try to add that code

Comment: Actually, @Rory I have already written the code the only thing is about height of the tables . that I am getting how do I set it in the percentage in according with the remaining height of the page.

Comment: To be honest I think you're over complicating this, I don't see why you even need to get any remaining heights if you just want the first table to be 30% height and the second to be 70% height, just set the height values to that. If that's not working, then this is why we need to see your code. I understand you may have a lot of code, but just simplify it to a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are asking for. Get remaining height and multiply it with the % you need.

```
.my-first-table {
    height: calc((100vh - 161px) * 0.3);
}
.my-second-table {
    height: calc((100vh - 161px) * 0.7);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking  for